# Looking for large latex file (~200 pages/1mb+) to test compression implementations

Tags: latex, compression, text-files

as the title suggests I'm looking for latex-specific files that are around 200 pages and 1mb+ in size. I've tried looking around but I can only really find templates, and the only other idea I had would be to concatenate random latex files together. Is there a link online that has a collection of such files, or does anyone have one I could use? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the documentations of latex packages? For example the beamer user guide has about 250 pages and 1.6 MB https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/tree/master/doc

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own if you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

The above code produces a 230-page (~650kb) Lorem ipsum treasure trove.

Alternatively here are some documentation pages (as suggested in the comments) consisting of various text/graphic/font-rich compilations of TeX-specific elements:

- [PGF manual](//texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) (~1,300 pages, ~10mb, graphic rich)
- [PStricks manual](//texdoc.net/pkg/pstricks) (~340 pages, ~5mb, graphic rich)
- [`memoir` user guide](//texdoc.net/pkg/memoir) (~600 pages, ~3mb)
- [`beamer` user guide](//texdoc.net/pkg/beamer) (~250 pages, ~2mb)
- [LaTeX2e source documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/source2e) (~700 pages, ~3mb)
- [TeX by Topic](//texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic) (~300 pages, ~1mb)
- [`biblatex` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex) (~340 pages, ~2mb)
- [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive) (~340 pages, ~9mb, font-rich)

Comment: "Flawless Victory" ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Lorem Ipsum generator that give you the ability to determine the number of genereted byte in the final document like: https://www.lipsum.com/